# Sounds are not working on Mountain Lion Notification Center

Tags: macos, notifications, audio

Although I see an option in System Preferences > Notifications to enable applications to pop a sound on new notifications, Mountain Lion is not actually playing those sounds.

Has Anyone run into similar problem?

Comment: Many notifications don't have sound effects. Have you tried for example adding a reminder at Reminders.app?

Comment: Thanks for answering.

I've just tested the Reminder Notification: no sounds at all, even tough Notification Settings for Reminder app has all the three features enabled (notification, badge and sound).

Any other idea?

Comment: Sorry my terrible einglish. I have same problem exactly. The sounds of some notifications of some programs of the center of notifications do not work (Capucin, Tweetbot), however others works o.k. (mail,mensajes). I think that many applications even aren'y ready to work with the center of notifications especially the sound the sound.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my mother's new iMac to Mountain Lion and noticed that the mail sending and receiving sounds were not occurring.  I found the following URL which was a temporary fix, but the problem comes back... so I think there's a bug here.

You might try the following to see if this helps:

http://applehelpwriter.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/no-sound-or-volume-after-upgrading/

Lynn